# How do I number the rows in a .tbl output file using IDL?

Tags: idl

I've written about 150 lines of good code that takes several FITS files, merges them together, and prints an output file in table format. I'm trying to print a number at the beginning of each row of the output file so that I can get an easy count (line item number). Ive been searching the net for over an hour, but just cannot figure out a simple way to do this. I know this must have a simple solution, but I am extremely new to programming and having a tough time.

Comment: If you are referring to [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_(programming_language)), and if you are using a `FOR` loop to write to this file, then just add another column that corresponds to the `FOR` loop index.  This will give you line numbers.  If you don't like it starting at zero, add +1 to the index when writing it to the file.

Comment: I am  using IDL as well as a FOR loop. How can I add another column that will correspond to the FOR loop index?

Comment: Why don't you show the code that prints the output file?

Comment: Just do something like:  `FOR j=0L, n - 1L DO PRINTF, j, [rest of stuff in file]`  Make sure to change the `FORMAT` statement accordingly (i.e., add an `I`).